# Decryption in AES 256 in Android getting NumberFormateException

Tags: android, encryption

I am working on SOAP parsing sending request to Dot.net server.

Response is Encrypted on the server side by AES 256 algorithm. the response from the server is

> k/tMHkiyWgoof8FAsTJttWZT7sku5QcJe6iZsWjkPXS+xE7ujjPn/f0E8sqWkXLH0jiXXHYwrV1SdJjbnXsiXxitfnAB83uIOr3VunB3fMVCOxTHk+Ej4mx+hBNB9pkJlgOJfTPX666fn6mwbkmFE4uqhTVbdGjm9HiSAW0mm91UANu3EERLS8g0UUPNdHn1

Now I am using the decryption method in java files as:

```
**public class SimpleCrypto {
public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyb = seed.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(keyb);
    SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
    byte[] clearbyte = dcipher.doFinal(toByte(encrypted));
    return new String(clearbyte);
}
public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `toByte` function doesn't make any sense. Encrypted response is not a Hex String(A hex `String` has only 0123456789ABCDEF characters). So you treat your response as if it is a hex `String` and convert it to `byte[]`.

You need to know the encoding used on the server when it converts encrypted data to `String` and you should use the same encoding to get the `byte[]` back from the response `String`. So try

```
encrypted.getBytes(YOUR_RESPONSE_ENCODING);
```

**EDIT**

Also your cipher should use the same algorithm used on the server to encrypt, in my case I'm using:

```
new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding");
```

Note: We also use AES 256 encryption. But there are many ways to encrypt data using AES 256. You need to know the exact algorithm and padding method used on your server.

If you get `BadPaddingException` that means your data length is not an exact multiple of your key length. So in your case, `encrypted.getBytes(YOUR_RESPONSE_ENCODING).length % thedigest.length` must be equal to `0`. You should add zero bytes to the end of your data so that this constraint is satisfied.

There is a excellent guide to cryptography here:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/index.shtml

Comment: dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
     byte[] clearbyte = dcipher.doFinal(encrypted.getByte(UTF8));

Comment: dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
     byte[] clearbyte = dcipher.doFinal(encrypted.getByte(UTF8));  After using ur suggest code I m getting Bad Padding Exception.  M i doing anything wrong......!

Comment: Try `new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding");`